# Posting httr request to API with xmlquery in body

Tags: r, xml, httr

I am trying to retrieve data from an API with stock data from this site: nasdaqomxnordic.com.

So far, I have succesfully constructed a curl call by inspecting the page in Google Chrome. The curl call works great when I send it from reqbin.com and I receive the expected data.

However, when I try to translate it into an httr request in R, I can't make it work. It seems that httr connects succesfully to the server, but nothing happens after that - the command just keeps running forever in r, until I cancel it manually. I suspect that the issue lies in how the body of the request (the xmlquery) is sent so I have tried various formats and tried curlconverter.com, but with no luck (see code below).

Do you guys have any idea about what could be wrong?

**The curl code looks like this (this works perfectly on reqbin.com):**

```
curl 'https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx' \
  -H 'authority: www.nasdaqomxnordic.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: se-SE,se;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/microsite?Instrument=CSE1158&name=Novo%20Nordisk%20B&ISIN=DK0060534915' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  --data-raw 'xmlquery=%3Cpost%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Exchange%22+value%3D%22NMF%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22SubSystem%22+value%3D%22History%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Action%22+value%3D%22GetDataSeries%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22AppendIntraDay%22+value%3D%22no%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Instrument%22+value%3D%22CSE1158%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22FromDate%22+value%3D%222021-12-25%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ToDate%22+value%3D%222022-12-25%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22hi__a%22+value%3D%220%2C5%2C6%2C3%2C1%2C2%2C4%2C21%2C8%2C10%2C12%2C9%2C11%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt%22+value%3D%22%2FnordicV3%2Fhi_csv.xsl%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22OmitNoTrade%22+value%3D%22true%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_lang%22+value%3D%22en%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_options%22+value%3D%22%2Cadjusted%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_contenttype%22+value%3D%22application%2Fms-excel%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_contenttypefilename%22+value%3D%22NOVO_B-2021-12-25-2022-12-25.csv%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_hiddenattrs%22+value%3D%22%2Civ%2Cip%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_tableId%22+value%3D%22historicalTable%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22DefaultDecimals%22+value%3D%22false%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22app%22+value%3D%22%2Faktier%2Fmicrosite%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fpost%3E' \
  --compressed
```

**My best try at an httr equivalent look like this:**

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `authority` = 'www.nasdaqomxnordic.com',
  `accept` = '*/*',
  `accept-language` = 'se-SE,se;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
  `content-type` = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  `origin` = 'https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com',
  `referer` = 'https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/microsite?Instrument=CSE1158&name=Novo%20Nordisk%20B&ISIN=DK0060534915',
  `sec-ch-ua` = '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
  `sec-ch-ua-mobile` = '?0',
  `sec-ch-ua-platform` = '"Windows"',
  `sec-fetch-dest` = 'empty',
  `sec-fetch-mode` = 'cors',
  `sec-fetch-site` = 'same-origin',
  `user-agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  `x-requested-with` = 'XMLHttpRequest'
)

data = 'xmlquery=%3Cpost%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Exchange%22+value%3D%22NMF%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22SubSystem%22+value%3D%22History%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Action%22+value%3D%22GetDataSeries%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22AppendIntraDay%22+value%3D%22no%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Instrument%22+value%3D%22CSE1158%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22FromDate%22+value%3D%222021-12-25%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ToDate%22+value%3D%222022-12-25%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22hi__a%22+value%3D%220%2C5%2C6%2C3%2C1%2C2%2C4%2C21%2C8%2C10%2C12%2C9%2C11%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt%22+value%3D%22%2FnordicV3%2Fhi_csv.xsl%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22OmitNoTrade%22+value%3D%22true%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_lang%22+value%3D%22en%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_options%22+value%3D%22%2Cadjusted%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_contenttype%22+value%3D%22application%2Fms-excel%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_contenttypefilename%22+value%3D%22NOVO_B-2021-12-25-2022-12-25.csv%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_hiddenattrs%22+value%3D%22%2Civ%2Cip%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_tableId%22+value%3D%22historicalTable%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22DefaultDecimals%22+value%3D%22false%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22app%22+value%3D%22%2Faktier%2Fmicrosite%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fpost%3E'


http_response <- httr::POST(url = 'https://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data, verbose())
```

I have also tried this alternate formatting of the data-part of the request, but with no better luck:

````
data = list(
  `xmlquery` = '<post>\n<param name="Exchange" value="NMF"/>\n<param name="SubSystem" value="History"/>\n<param name="Action" value="GetDataSeries"/>\n<param name="AppendIntraDay" value="no"/>\n<param name="Instrument" value="CSE1158"/>\n<param name="FromDate" value="2021-12-25"/>\n<param name="ToDate" value="2022-12-25"/>\n<param name="hi__a" value="0,5,6,3,1,2,4,21,8,10,12,9,11"/>\n<param name="ext_xslt" value="/nordicV3/hi_csv.xsl"/>\n<param name="OmitNoTrade" value="true"/>\n<param name="ext_xslt_lang" value="en"/>\n<param name="ext_xslt_options" value=",adjusted,"/>\n<param name="ext_contenttype" value="application/ms-excel"/>\n<param name="ext_contenttypefilename" value="NOVO_B-2021-12-25-2022-12-25.csv"/>\n<param name="ext_xslt_hiddenattrs" value=",iv,ip,"/>\n<param name="ext_xslt_tableId" value="historicalTable"/>\n<param name="DefaultDecimals" value="false"/>\n<param name="app" value="/aktier/microsite"/>\n</post>'
)
```
````

Comment: Hmmm...with R 4.2.1 on Ubuntu, I get a completed response back with your first R code block without any hung processing and can build a data frame: `nasdaq_df <- read.csv(text=gsub(";\n", "\n", gsub("sep=;|\r", "", httr::content(http_response, as="text"))), sep=";")`.

Comment: @Parfait: Thank very much for trying the code. Odd that it works on your machine. I have now tried adressing all kinds of issues I can think about: I have updated R to 4.2.2 (I came from 4.1.3), I have updated R Studio to 2022.12.0 and I have reinstalled httr and made sure it is the latest version. But I still get the same issue (httr seems to connect to the server, but the command keeps running indefinitely in R with no response). I am running a 64-bit Windows 10 machine by the way. Any ideas about what could be causing this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interestingly, I do reproduce your hanging issue on Windows 10. But I think the issue comes down to R's `httr` on Windows as I tested exact same curl request in [Python](https://hastebin.com/uwinirixax.py) and [PowerShell](https://hastebin.com/ganutahika.rb) and response returned immediately. Consider raising an issue with [httr authors](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues) with this reprex. Interestingly, a similar [RStudio forum question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/httr-get-hanging-with-no-response/111397) but with `httr::GET` went unanswered and also compared to Python.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I will try to take it up with the httr authors.